# JS does not display the result | Python | Eel

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, eel

I cannot solve the problem. I wrote a program, here is its short description:
An application whose logic is written in **python** and the interface is rendered using **HTML** and **CSS**. Python imported module **eel**. Python has a function that returns an array. In JS, a variable is created that takes the result of the function, and then the result is written to the HTML classes. This is how it looks:

- **Python code**

  ```
   import eel
   import datetime
   import sys


   eel.init("web")

   isoWD = datetime.datetime.today().isoweekday()

   @eel.expose
   def some_func():
       if isoWD == 1:
           result = ['elems', 'elems', 'elems', 'elems', 'elems', 'elems']

       elif isoWD == 2:
           result = ['elems', 'elems', 'elems', 'elems', 'elems', 'elems']

       elif isoWD == 3:
           result = ['elems', 'elems', 'elems', 'elems', 'elems', 'elems']

       elif isoWD == 4:
           result = ['elems', 'elems', 'elems', 'elems', 'elems', 'elems']

       elif isoWD == 5:
           result = ['elems', 'elems', 'elems', 'elems', 'elems', 'elems']

       elif isoWD == 6:
           result = ['elems', 'elems', 'elems', 'elems', 'elems', 'elems']

       elif isoWD == 7:
           sys.exit()

       return result


   eel.start("main.html", size=(325, 450))
  ```
- **HTML code**

```js
function display() {
  var res = eel.some_func();
  for (var i = 0; i <= 'block__les'.length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('block__les')[i].innerHTML = res[i];
  }
}
display();
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="block__num">
      <p>(1)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block__les"></div>
    <div class="block__time">09.00 - 09.30</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="block__num">
      <p>(2)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block__les"></div>
    <div class="block__time">09.40 - 10.10</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="block__num">
      <p>(3)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block__les"></div>
    <div class="block__time">10.20 - 10.50</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="block__num">
      <p>(4)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block__les"></div>
    <div class="block__time">11.00 - 11.30</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="block__num">
      <p>(5)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block__les"></div>
    <div class="block__time">11.40 - 12.10</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="block__num">
      <p>(6)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block__les"></div>
    <div class="block__time">12.20 - 12.50</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="block__num">
      <p>(7)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block__les"></div>
    <div class="block__time">13.00 - 13.30</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="block__num">
      <p>(8)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block__les"></div>
    <div class="block__time">13.40 - 14.10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Output:

[image: Output img]

Array elements should be output between numbers and time. But it's empty there.

Comment: You should use `await eel.some_func()()` and make the `display` function async

Comment: @mplungjan eel works like that to call a server function it’s not a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the results sent from the python function exposed to eel, the javascript function, **display**, should become **async** function and we should **await** the results come from the python function.

Therefore, the **display** function becomes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
async function display() {
  var res=await eel.some_func()();
  for (var i = 0; i <= document.getElementsByClassName('block__les').length ; i++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('block__les')[i].innerHTML = res[i];
  }
}
display();
</script>
```

Another thing should be mentioned, but it is not related to `eel`, in the `display` function, **'block__les'.length** does not give the number of items of class 'block__les', but it gives the number of characters of the word `block__les`, which is **10**.

and in order the number of items of class 'block__les', we could use **document.getElementsByClassName('block__les').length**,which gives **8**, the correct number.

of course, do not forget to put

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/eel.js"></script>
```

in the head section of the `main.html`

Finnaly do not forget to change:

```
result = ['elems', 'elems', 'elems', 'elems', 'elems', 'elems']
```

to become 8 items to match the number of the diplayed items in the HTML.

```
result = ['elems', 'elems', 'elems', 'elems', 'elems', 'elems', 'elems', 'elems']
```